# Xcode crash when click on general/build phases or any other tab

Tags: ios, xcode

I have installed Xcode7.3 and Xcode 8.1 and I have a older project of Xcode 7.3. I run the project in Xcode 8.1 works fine. But when I try to run in Xcode 7.3 it crashes when I try to tap/click on general or else.

[image]

after clicking any other tab it crashes and give

[image]

I searched the web and got a solution: delete xcuserdata in the contents of xcodeproj but didn't work.

OS: Mac OS Sierra 10.12.1

Answer (score 0):

you can use a utility I made for this, just repalce prj with your project file names, it will clean the miss and prevent xcode from crashing.

https://github.com/deya-eldeen/XCodeProjectCleaner

```
printf '\33c\e[3J'

RED=`tput setaf 1`
BLUE=`tput setaf 4`
NOCOLOR=`tput sgr0`

BASEDIR=$(dirname "$0")
path1="prj.xcodeproj/xcuserdata"
path2="prj.xcworkspace/xcuserdata"

echo "${BLUE}[XCode cache files pruner, created by Deya Eldeen Elkhawaldeh]${NOCOLOR}"
echo "REMOVING ${NOCOLOR} $BASEDIR/${RED}$path1${NOCOLOR}"
rm -R "$BASEDIR/$path1/"
echo "REMOVING ${NOCOLOR} $BASEDIR/${RED}$path2${NOCOLOR}"
rm -R "$BASEDIR/$path2/"

echo "${BLUE}Done,${NOCOLOR}"
```

also delete the files here

> ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState

and make it locked so xcode never writes there again.